# Solving an integral with square root in the exponent

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve to following integral (related to a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195210/integrate-a-3d-gaussian-over-a-sphere))
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\exp{(Ax^2+Bx+C+(Dx+E)\sqrt{1-x^2})}dx$$
Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known closed-formula for the reduced case $B=C=D=E=0$ so I highly doubt you can find any magic answer. If you are lucky enough you will potentially end up using special functions like [incomplete Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), which is not very easy to use.

If you are comfortable with approaching this integral numerically, I suggest using adaptive [Gaussian quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) with a sufficient number of roots.

Comment: I don't get it. In your reduced case $\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(Ax^2) dx=2\exp(Ax^2)$

Comment: This is not correct. $\int_{-1}^1 \exp(Ax^2) dx$ cannot be solved explicitely because of the square. If an $x$ is put in front of the exponential then you can integrate, but there is no such thing here.

Comment: Sorry, copy&paste error. Maple gave this answer $\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(Ax^2)=\sqrt{\frac{-\pi}{A}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{-A})$

Comment: Another [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28a*z%5E2%29+dz+z%3D-1..1)

Comment: Both solutions you provided are not closed-formulae. Look at the definition of $\rm erf$ ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. It seems I'll have to tackle my [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195210/integrate-a-3d-gaussian-over-a-sphere?lq=1) differently.