# Integral of a function of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

I've been trying to solve the integral of the following function of cosines with Weierstrass substitution
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}S}{-S_2}\exp(S^2)(1+\text{erf}(S))\text{d}x$$
$$S=\frac{S_{1}}{2\sqrt{-S_{2}}}$$
$$S_{1}=A_{1}\cos(x+\delta_{1})$$
$$S_{2}=A_{2}\cos(2x+\delta_{2})+B_2\quad\quad (S_2<0)$$
As this is not a rational function of trigonometric functions, I failed. Which other techniques can I try to solve this? This integral is related to [a previous attempt to integrate a 3D Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195210/integrate-a-3d-gaussian-over-a-sphere).

Comment: What makes you think, that this can be solved (whatever that means)? I mean, another way than numerically...

Comment: (whatever that means): solve this definite integral... As for this integral having an analytical solution: I'm not sure, I just wanted to ask whether anyone had an idea on how to approach this.